# npx create-next-app <project-name> is not working

Tags: node.js, npm, next.js

I typed npx create-next-app .

Then I got this error message.

```
npm ERR! cb.apply is not a function

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\****\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-05-29T04_42_06_423Z-debug.log
```

Also Tried

```
yarn create next-app .
npm cache clean --force
updating the version of node and npm
```

Oddly, npx create-react-app . is working.

I don't know what to do to solve this issue now.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

install following package

```
npm install graceful-fs --save-dev
```